# Increase number of lines shown in a Stack Trace

Tags: java, error-handling, stack-trace

So I’m writing a program and an error is shown, as I’m reading the stack trace I come to the end and it says “... 20 more”. Is there any way to see these 20 more lines?

Comment: Not an answer, but most of the time I find that the first 20 lines is sufficient to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Well I am able to tell it’s a “Java.io.fileNotFoundException” but I can’t find the file that actually looks for the missing file (I moved the “missing” file to a new location)

Answer (score 0):

If you can catch the exception, you can loop through the lines and print them yourself using the [getStackTrace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace()) method.